# *.ini file not reflected in RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am creating an RCP application in Mac using Eclipse Photon. 
When I try to export the build, the .app file does not contain the executable file. It is present outside in a MacOs folder. If I place the executable file inside the .app file, the application gets launched as expected.

The issue I am facing is that the application is not reading the contents in the .ini file.
If there is anything I am doing wrong or anything that I can do to rectify this is needed.

Edit:

The exported product looks like this [image: scrrenshot1]

When I click show package contents in .app file, It looks like this
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: How are you exporting the RCP **exactly**? Note that maven + tycho is now the recommended way to build an RCP. Also note that Eclipse 2019-09 is the current release of Eclipse, Photon is 5 releases out of date.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. The tycho building approach is being worked on. In the meantime, any way I can make the application read the .ini file?

Comment: What you describe is not what I would expect from a RCP export. So you need to tell us **exactly** what  you are doing. Check that there is no logs.zip file being produced by the build.

Comment: @greg-449, I have edited the post for better clarity. If the first image is because of my mistake, Please point it out.

Comment: That doesn't look right at all. Again how are you doing this build? We can't tell you what you are doing wrong if we don't know what you are doing!

Comment: I am exporting the build directly from Eclipse. By clicking export from the .product file.